# How will I use exception handling in this?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this piece of code

```
def airplaneDetails():
if choice == '2':
    a1 = input('Enter the type of aircraft: ')
    a1 = a1.capitalize()
    airplane_info = open('airplane.csv', 'r')
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(airplane_info,delimiter = ',',fieldnames=('Body_type','Running_cost','Max_flight','Capacity','first_class'))
    userdata['Maximum flight range'] = int(air_data[a1]['Maximum flight range (km)'])
    for row in csvreader:
         if row['Body_type'] == a1:
            print(row)

d1 = int(input('Enter number of first class seats on the aircraft: '))
if d1 != 0:
    if d1 < air_data[a1]['Minimum number of first class seats']:
        print('Error: First class seats lower then minimum')
        menu()
    elif d1 > 0.5 * air_data[a1]['Capacity if all seats are standard class']:
        print('Error: There are more first class seats then half the capacity of normal seats')
        menu()
    userdata['Numfirstclass'] = d1
    userdata['Running cost per seat per 100km'] = air_data[a1]['Running cost per seat per 100km']
    userdata['Capacity if all seats are standard class'] = int(air_data[a1]['Capacity if all seats are standard class'])
else:
    print('Error 0 is not valid value')
userdata['Number of standard class seats'] = air_data[a1]['Capacity if all seats are standard class'] - d1 * 2
menu()
```

I want to use try/except if I get a 'keyerror' or a 'value error, how would I do it? I think that I will have to put try at the start but I got no clue about the except as when I tried it, it just wouldn't work so could anyone help please?

Comment: Hey, please try yourself with some debug: use only one variable, print what the variable contain. A key error is that you try to access some data in a dict that is actually not there. So check for that. Once you identify the variable that does not have the expected key, check why.